# how to run a View's constructor if using browser back button

Tags: backbone.js

The gist of this question is that If I use Backbone.js code to clean up my views (i.e. to prevent zombie views), then I am unable to set the element of a view if I click the back button in the browser, and therefore the view is not getting rendered properly in situations where I click the back button.

Details

I have a PostsView that displays a list of posts. In the constructor I call setElement and then render each member of the list using multiple PostListViews

```
export class PostsView extends Backbone.View{
      constructor(options){
         this.setElement($('#main'), true)
         super()
         this.render()
       }
      addEachPost(model){
       new PostListView({model: model });
      }
      render(){
         this.collection.each(this.addEachPost, this);
      }
```

If I click one of the PostListViews, then the router loads that PostListView onto the page, and if I click the back button, it reloads the Posts view onto the page, but only if I haven't cleaned up the Posts view.For example, with this code below (that doesn't clean up views), I can hit the back button and then another link and so on and it continues to load everything fine, but it'll eventually create zombies because I'm not cleaning up the views

Router

```
 export class MyRouter extends Backbone.Router{

           constructor(options){
              '': 'renderList',
              'post/:id': 'showPost'
           }
           renderList(){
             new PostsView({collection: this.collection)};
           }
           showPost(id){
             //code ommitted
             new PostView({model: modle})
           }

 }
```

So, with the code below, I introduced some oft-used code (that I've seen in other Backbone applications) to prevent zombie views, but now if I do, when I hit the back button, the PostsView doesn't get rendered to the page

Router code to clean up zombie

```
changeView(view){
     if (this.currentView){
        this.currentView.close();
     }
     this.currentView = view;

}
```

in the router, I then load views by calling

```
         `this.changeView( new PostsView({collection: this.collection)});`
```

However, if I do this, I can load the PostsView initially, but if I click one of the memebers of the list and then click the back, the Posts view is not loading on the page. I noticed from inspecting the console that, in this situation (after clicking the back button), the `el` is not set to `#main`, which is why it's not getting onto the page. In the code where I DON't clean up the zombie views, the `el` is still set to `#main` if I hit the back button --so obviously it seems as if my code to clean up the zombie views does something to prevent #main being set if I hit the back button. So, by cleaning up the zombies, I've deleted the el and it's not getting set again because the constructor is not run when I hit the `back` button.

Question: is there some way to use the Router code that cleans up the zombie views, but at the same time to ensure that the constructor is run when I hit the back button in the browser? If the constructor for a view is run even when I hit the back button, then I believe it will set the Element (as it did on page load)

Comment: Could you please fix your question: the sentence seems to stop in the middle at `[...] the vi` (just edit, don't comment "edited", thanks :)

Comment: @try-catch-finally ok, I fixed that part and tried to clarify more in other places. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see from your code that you call View.remove() but suppose it's inside this.currentView.close() - remove function (http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) do the proper cleanup but also removes #main element from the page. So if you have more views sharing same (existing) element you can't call remove. You have to do the cleanup by calling undelegateEvents (for DOM cleanup), stopListening (for model events cleanup) and if the other view is not immediately rendered you can also call this.$el.html("") to empty it.

I'd suggest to do the cleanup in overridden router's execute function (http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute)

EDIT:

When creating view in backbone you have two options how to create its element:

1) either use existing DOM element

```js
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // selector text..
  $el: "#main",
  render: function () {
    // visible immediatelly
    this.$el.html("<p>content</p>");
    return this;
  }
});
```

2) or have new element created by the view

```js
var MyView = Backbone.View.Extend({
  // div is default - you don't have to specify it...
  tagName: 'div',
  render: function () {
    // not visible - this.$el is not live DOM element
    this.$el.html("<p>content</p>");
    return this;
  }
});

// ..
// outer mechanism
var myView = new MyView();
$("body").append(myView.render().$el);
```

In second case, it is not live DOM element and must be appended to DOM by some mechanism outside the view itself (because view should know only about its element and you need to use some element above)

When destroying view there is also several scenarios. If you call remove() on view, it does all the needed cleanup - it calls jQuery's remove() which unbind all DOM events (remove the element from DOM!) and also calls stopListening() on the view which unbinds all Model events (I refer here to latest Backbone 1.2.3).

So you usually use remove() on #2 type views. If you have #1 type view you can also destroy it by remove() but you can't create another instance because the element no longer exists (unless you create new one by some outer mechanism which could bring mess to your code quickly..) Instead of remove you have to do the cleanup by calling view.undelegateEvents() for DOM events and view.stopListening() for killing bounded Model events. Now the element remains in DOM and you can create new view instance while the previous view RIP with no ghosts around.

BTW: You can also have multiple views sharing the same element - one for rendering, other to handle (logically grouped) events - then you have to use the non remove cleanup if you wan't to close just one of them (or switch some behaviour temporarily).

Regarding your case - it is combination of what I have just described:

```js
// ..
// #2 type view
var PostListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  render: function () {
    this.$el.html('<a href="#posts/' + this.model.getId() + '">' + this.model.getName() + '</a>');
    return this;
  }
});

// ..
// #1 type view
var PostDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
  $el: "#main",
  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(/* ... */);
    return this;
  },
  close: function () {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.stopListening();
  }
});

// ..
// #1 type view
var PostsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  $el: "#main",
  render: function () {
    var $list = $("<ul></ul>");
    
    // you need to store reference to the item views
    this.postListLtemViews = this.collection.reduce(function (list, item) {
      var postListItemView = new PostListItemView({
        model: item
      }); 
      
      // 'outer mechanism' to insert #2 type view to DOM
      $list.append(postListItemView.render().$el);
      list.push(postListItemView);
      
      return list;
    }, []);
    
    this.$el.html($list);
    return this;
  },
  close: function () {
    _.each(this.postListLtemViews, function (postListItemView) {
      postListItemView.remove();
    });
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.stopListening();
  }
});

// ..
// Router
var App = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "posts": "postsList",
    "posts/:id": "postDetail"
  },

  execute: function (callback, args, name) {
    // Cleanup
    if ( this.currentView ) {
      this.currentView.close();
    }
    
    // Apply route function
    if ( callback ) {
      callback.apply(this, args);
    }
  },
  
  postsList: function () {
    this.currentView = new PostsListView({
      collection: ...
    });
      
    this.currentView.render();
  },

  postDetail: function (id) {
    this.currentView = new PostDetailView({
      model: ...
    });
      
    this.currentView.render();
  }

});
```

Comment: thank you very much but if I don't `remove` the views, each time that I go from the list to showing a member of the list, I'm creating the list view each time in the router, and also a new view each time I view a member. Won't all these new PostView creations pile up and create a problem? which of your clean up techniques deal with that?  can you show me with a code sample how you'd override `Router-execute` to deal with it?

Comment: Could you show me how is this.currentView.close() function implemented? Because this is not a standard View function...

Comment: OK, I misread your comment, so there is 'remove' call in the close function.. I'll update my answer  with some code example.

Comment: I won't be able to test it until tomorrow. Thank you for the detailed answer. I've given you an upvote already and will accept it tomorrow if it works.

Comment: this is awesome. There's one small problem (for me) though. In the PostsListsView you do `var $list = $("<ul></ul>"); .... this.$el.html($list);` i.e. you render one DOM element (which contains the item views that you've called render on). However, I was using PostsListsView as my home page and the list wasn't the only part of it. I thought I could pass `$list` as a variable to a large template `template({ posts: $list });` but since `$list` already contains rendered item elements, it's not working. i.e. I can't loop over them in the template.  Is there a fix for that?

Comment: i.e. should I render PostsListsView inside a large homeView?

Comment: PostsListView (and PostDetailView) expects that there is live element with id="main". If you have other parts (rendered by other views) then the base markup could look like `<body><div id="other-part1"></div><div id="posts"></div><div id="other-part2"></div>...</body>` (and of course change #main to #posts)